# .NET 6 | C# | Blazor Server websocket connection failed after openid auth

Tags: .net, websocket, blazor, openid, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Blazor Server app, which is hosted on our VPS in docker, behind nginx reverse proxy.
If I go to the web, it's okay and all is clear and working.
[image]
But if I login via openid (keycloak), after redirecting back with all cookies and JWT's - app cannot connect to websocket.
[image]

I tried all variety of nginx configuration, but I don't think it's on nginx side at this point. Connection without authorization is ok. Maybe it's some kind of configuration which I'm missing?

I appreciate any help.
Thank you.

EDIT:
Solved thanks to @thrsn

Add

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
```

to the nginx config (at least I had to) between http {..}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't found the solution for this or you are someone looking for the answer as I was:

I have just been in the same situation as you (.NET 6 Blazor with Keycloak behind nginx) and I figured out that the issue lies in the size of the cookies generated from Blazor+Keycloak. They exceed the normal 8192 bytes of large_client_header_buffers: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers

I increased the limit to:

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
```

And this solved my issue!

NB the override should be inside the **server** { ... } nginx tag.

Comment: You are the best, it helped!

I had to put  large_client_header_buffers 4 32k; into http {} in base config, but it works. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**POSSIBLY, the only last step is required(?).**

For those who will try to find this later: for me, following helped:

1. Adding [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configureiconfiguration) to my config.
2. Making `upstream helloapp` in 443 port in `nginx.conf` direct to `5001` port (instead of `5000`) and making `proxy_pass https://helloapp` instead of `proxy_pass http://helloapp`
3. Adding this to my `location / { proxy_pass https://helloapp; ... }`:

```
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

Advice from above were taken from [this absolute github hero](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/979#issuecomment-337934638).